# Issues getting bind_results to work in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, bind

I am attempting to loop through my bind_results, but it is not working like I need it to. I have tried this 20 different ways and the result is always the same. I get only the first records of `$survey_user_id` and `$survey_result` to echo out.

Also when I do a `COUNT` like I did in my query, do I need to loop through that as well? Because as of now it is only counting 1 record when there is multiple id's for rating_draft_result.id .

```
try {
$survey_title_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rating_draft_result.id), rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result 
                    FROM rating_draft_result
                    INNER JOIN users ON
                    rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
                    AND rating_draft_result.result = users.id");

if ( !$survey_title_stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Survey SELECT total count prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
if(!$survey_title_stmt->execute()) {
        die('Survey SELECT total count execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($survey_title_stmt->error));
}
 $survey_title_stmt->store_result();
} catch (Exception $e ) {
    die("Survey SELECT total count: " . $e->getMessage());
}
    $survey_title_stmt->bind_result($survey_id, $survey_user_id, $survey_result);
while ($survey_title_stmt->fetch()) {
    $survey_id;
    $survey_user_id;
    $survey_result;
}
?>              
                <div class="survey_results_out">
                    <div id="survey_results_title">Survey Results</div>
                        <div class="survey_popup_container">
                            <a class="survey_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">Who drafted best results</a>
                            <div id="">Users that completed this survey</div><?php echo $survey_id; ?>
                            <div class="survey_popup_wrap light_admin">
                                <a class="close_survey_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">X</a>
                                <div id="indexpopupTitleWrap">
                                    <div id="indexpopupTitle">Results of who drafted the best</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="survey_results_content_wrap">
                                    <div id="survey_results_content_usernames">
<?php                                   
    echo $survey_user_id;
    echo $survey_result;
?>
```

My database tables look like this...

```
users
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

rating_draft_result
CREATE TABLE `rating_draft_result` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `result` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
users  id``firstname``lastname``email``phone_number``username``password``salt``joined group

 1   Jack   Johnson  jack@email.com  2222  jackusername  ffd  fdddfd  today  1
 10   Tom   Thompson  fdfdfddf@fef.com 5555  Tomusername


rating_draft_result
     `id` `user_id` `result`
      20    1         10
```

I want to be able to match the rating_draft_result's user_id and result with the user table's id field.

So I want to get the jackusername and tomusername fields.

Comment: When I enter this into phpmyadmin SQL, I get only one result to. So what in my query would be causing this to only `SELECT` one result?

Comment: Your main select has COUNT (an aggregate function) with no group by clause. In effect this is getting the count of non null *rating_draft_result.id* along with random values of *rating_draft_result.user_id* and *rating_draft_result.result* . Probably just needs *GROUP BY rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result* adding to the query

Comment: Like this? `SELECT COUNT(rating_draft_result.id), rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result 
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users ON
rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
AND rating_draft_result.result = users.id                                 GROUP BY rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result`

Comment: Yes, like that. Aggregate function roll up all the results in to one row (performing their function on all the rows). You can use GROUP BY to roll them up in to groups of rows.

Comment: @Kickstart I tried this and it didn't help,

Comment: In what way doesn't it help? Can you post the table declares, a bit of sample data and the result you want from the query?

Comment: The count still shows 1 and my query is not getting all of the results from the rating_draft_result table. I updated my question to show some more info.

Comment: When I had this simple query... `SELECT COUNT(id), user_id, result 
      FROM rating_draft_result` I got all of the records I was going after. The only reason I brought in the users table is because I want to match the user_id and result with the users table id, so that I can echo out the usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what it is you want for that data.

However the following might help:-

This gets the *rating_draft_result.id* and the 2 user names that go with it

```
SELECT rating_draft_result.id, u1.username, u2.username 
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users u1 ON rating_draft_result.user_id =  u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON rating_draft_result.result = u2.id
```

This gets the count of *rating_draft_result.id* for each pair set of usernames in the rating_draft_result table

```
SELECT COUNT(rating_draft_result.id), u1.username, u2.username 
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users u1 ON rating_draft_result.user_id =  u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON rating_draft_result.result = u2.id
GROUP BY u1.username, u2.username
```

Comment: I made a survey. `rating_draft_result.user_id` is the id of the user who filled it out. `rating_draft_result.result` is the id of the user they chose. In my users table the id is the user's id. So, I am just trying to match the `rating_draft_result.user_id` and `rating_draft_result.result` to that users.id so I can call out the username.

Comment: Probably the 2nd query then.

Comment: I just tried both. Both echo out only one username. The first shows a count of 26 when it should be 2. I think it is counting the amount of records from the users table and the rating_draft_result table. It also is only showing one username for the user_id and result. The second query only shows one for the count. It also only shows one user_id and result record.

Comment: The results should be showing. Bob   Dave /////////// Tom   Sue...The /// representing a new row.... What this is doing is just  Bob   Dave

Comment: Can you put the table and a couple of sample rows on to http://www.sqlfiddle.com which demonstrate the issue. Neither query should give you what you say if I understand you data correctly. Might take me a while to reply (about to go home so will check later).

Comment: here is the fiddle. I created it with my initial query. However, with my query on my site I get 1 to show up. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89be1/1 ... I am just trying to get the usernames for the `rating_draft_result` query to show up for both the `user_id` and `result` usernames. Then count the amount of id's the `rating_draft_result' has.

Comment: That is what my 2nd query does. It is coming up with a count of 1 as with your test data each combination of username only occurs only once on rating_draft_result.

Comment: But I should have more than one record/set of data. In my real set of data, it should be counting two as I have had two people fill out the survey. So it should show something like.... Bob filled out the survey, he chose Tom... Rob filled out the survey and he selected Pete.

Comment: That is what the 2nd one does - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89be1/6 . Unless you want the count column to be a count of all the matches, or all the matches for one user rather than a count of all that combination of matches.

Comment: That corrected it. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks!